# "nth not supported" on PersistentHashSet when destructuring Set in Loop header

Tags: clojure, set, destructuring

Clojure noob here.

I want to pull the front and rest out of a Set. Doing `(front #{1})` and `(rest #{1})` produce `1` and `()` respectively, which is mostly what I'd expect.

However in the code below, I use the destructuring `[current-node & open-nodes] #{start}` in my loop to pull something out of the set (at this point I don't really care about if it was the first or last item. I just want this form working) and it breaks.

Here's my function, half-implementing a grid search:

```
(defn navigate-to [grid start dest]
  "provides route from start to dest, not including start"
  (loop [[current-node & open-nodes] #{start} ;; << throws exception
         closed-nodes #{}]
    (if (= dest current-node)
      [] ;; todo: return route
      (let [all-current-neighbours (neighbours-of grid current-node) ;; << returns a set
            open-neighbours (set/difference all-current-neighbours closed-nodes)]
        (recur (set/union open-nodes open-neighbours)
               (conj closed-nodes current-node))))))
```

When stepping through (with Cider), on the start of the first loop, it throws this exception:

```
UnsupportedOperationException nth not supported on this type: PersistentHashSet  clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom (RT.java:933)
```

I could use a nested let form that does first/rest manually, but that seems wasteful. Is there a way to get destructured Sets working like this in the loop form? Is it just not supported on Sets?

Comment: I know there's no implicit ordering, but figured if first/rest worked then this destructuring would work. Is that an inconsistency in clojure or am I misunderstanding a subtlety?

Comment: ...if I changed to a vec, then I'd also have to do those set operations differently, which would be awkward.

Comment: Update: destructuring is being tweaked for Clojure 1.9, and the code shown here will no longer throw the ‘nth not supported’ exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by others you cannot bind a set to a vector literal, because a set is not sequential. So even this simple `let` fails with *nth not supported*:

```
(let [[x] #{1}])
```

You could work around this by "destructuring" the set with the use of `first` and `disj`:

```
(loop [remaining-nodes #{start}
       closed-nodes #{}]
    (let [current-node (first remaining-nodes)
          open-nodes   (disj  remaining-nodes current-node)]
        ;; rest of your code ...
    ))
```

Using `(rest remaining-nodes)` instead of `(disj remaining-nodes current-node)` could be possible, but as sets are unordered, `rest` is in theory not obliged to take out the same element as was extracted with `first`. Anyway `disj` will do the job.

NB: be sure to detect *remaining-nodes* being *nil*, which could lead to an endless loop.

## Algorithm for returning the route

For implementing the missing part in the algorithm (returning the route) you could maintain
a map of paths. It would have one path for each visited node: a vector with the nodes leading from the start node to that node, keyed by that node.

You could use `reduce` to maintain that map of paths as you visit new nodes. With a new function used together with that `reduce` and an added *nil* test, the program could look like this:

```
(defn add-path [[path paths] node]
    "adds a node to a given path, which is added to a map of paths, keyed by that node"
    [path (assoc paths node (conj path node))])

(defn navigate-to [grid start dest]
    "provides route from start to dest, including both"
    (loop [remaining-nodes #{start}
           closed-nodes    #{}
           paths           (hash-map start [start])]
        (let [current-node           (first remaining-nodes)
              current-path           (get paths current-node)
              all-current-neighbours (neighbours-of grid current-node)
              open-neighbours        (set/difference all-current-neighbours closed-nodes)]
            (if (contains? #{dest nil} current-node)
                current-path ;; search complete
                (recur (set/union (disj remaining-nodes current-node) open-neighbours)
                    (conj closed-nodes current-node)
                    (second (reduce add-path [current-path paths] open-neighbours)))))))
```

The essence of the algorithm is still the same, although I merged the original `let` with the one needed for destructuring the nodes. This is not absolutely needed, but it probably makes the code more readable.

## Test

I tested this with a poor-mans definition of *grid* and *neighbours-of*, based on this graph (digits are nodes, bars indicate linked nodes:

```
0--1  2
|  |  |
3--4--5
|
6--7--8
```

This graph seems a good candidate for a test as it has a loop, a dead end, and is connected.

The graph is encoded with *grid* being a vector, where each element represents a node. An element's index in that vector is the node's identifier. The content of each element is a set of neighbours, making the *neighbours-of* function a trivial thing (your implementation will be different):

```
(def grid [#{1 3}   #{0 4}   #{5}
           #{0 4 6} #{1 3 5} #{2 4}
           #{3 7}   #{6 8}   #{7}  ])
          
(defn neighbours-of [grid node]
    (get grid node))
```

Then the test is to find the route from node 0 to node 8:

```
(println (navigate-to grid 0 8))
```

Output is:

```
[0 1 4 3 6 7 8]
```

This outcome demonstrates that the algoritm does not guarantee a shortest route, only that a route will be found if it exists. I suppose the outcome could be different on different engines, depending on how the Conjure internals decide which element to take from a set with `first`.

After removing one of the necessary node links, like the one between node 7 and 8, the output is *nil*.

NB: I found this an interesting question, and probably went a bit too far in my answer.

Comment: Cool stuff! Nice explanation of why not to use `rest`. I'm working towards dejkstra's alg, which should guarantee shortest path, and after that A*, which will avoid exploring unnecessary nodes.

Comment: Here's my functional djikstra, working on grids not networks: https://github.com/tenpn/clj_playground/blob/master/src/clj_playground/core.clj

Comment: Hey @tenpn, nice job!

Answer (score 3):

Sets are unordered, so positional destructuring doesn't make much sense.

According to the documentation for [Special Forms](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20(Destructuring)), which treats destructuring as well, sequential (vector) binding is specified to use `nth` and `nthnext` to look up the elements to bind.

> Vector binding-exprs allow you to bind names to parts of *sequential* things (not just vectors), like vectors, lists, seqs, strings, arrays, and anything that supports nth.

Clojure hash sets (being instances of `java.util.Set`) do not support lookup by index.

I don't know the context of your example code, but in any case pouring the set contents into an ordered collection, for example `(vec #{start})`, would make the destructuring work.

Comment: This really just moves the problem, as now I have to either do the set logic further down in some more longwinded way, or convert everything back _again_ into sets. That doesn't seem optimal.